# Open a form on button click in a carousel control

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a running carousel in my asp.net page. It displays 4 slides at a time. I want to keep a button at the button of each slide with the text "Register" and on a click; the user should see a form/panel opening towards the top but within the area of that particular slide of the carousel control. That form will just have first name, email, grade of the student as inputs and a submit button. Once input provided and clicked on submit; it should say thanks and that panel should auto-hide and the carousel should resume as usual. Any CSS/jQuery assistance to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: Check [how to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).  We would appreciate if you share your code first before seeking solutions. Please attach code of whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: please share your code